# Insufficient quota exists to complete the operation, net ads join

Tags: samba, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to join Active Directory in Xubuntu 16.04 in a enterprise business enviroment so I'll change the name of my REALM by MY.EXAMPLE.CORP. My issue is: when I run

```
net ads join -U Administrator
```

it appears:

```
Failed to join domain: failed to join domain 'MY.EXAMPLE.CORP' over rpc: Insufficient quota exists to complete the operation.
```

I tried the kinit and klist commands and the result is:

```
Tickect cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: Administrator@MY.EXAMPLE.CORP

Valid starting      Expires         Service principal
24/11/16 10:18:49   24/11/16 20:18:49   krbgt/MY.EXAMPLE.CORP@MY.EXAMPLE.CORP
    renew until   25/11/16 10:18:25
```

It means that kerberos is working well, it seems to be a problem of samba but I don't know what is wrong with my smb.conf file or if I'm missing something else. I've tried every thing that I've read but it still no working

These are the changes that I've done in every file. krb5.conf, smb.conf, nsswitch.conf

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.CORP

....

[realms]
DOMAIN = {
        kdc = SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP
        kdc = SERVER02.MY.DOMAIN.CORP
        admin_server = SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP SERVER.MY.DOMAIN.CORP
        default_domain = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    }

....


[domain_realm]
    SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    SERVER02.MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    .MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
    realm = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    security = ADS
    encrypt passwords = yes
    password server = SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP SERVER02.MYDOMAIN.CORP
    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap gid = 10000-20000
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = true
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    winbind use default domain = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
    winbind offline logon = yes
```

nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, an authenticated account can only join 10 machines to a domain so either the limit has to be increased or the account used needs to have create/delete computer objects rights on the container the machines are going into.

It's all explained here: http://atherbeg.com/2017/02/23/error-insufficient-quota-exists-to-complete-the-operation/